# Finding sum based on multiple columns from a file and display the highest value and the corresponding row using awk

Tags: bash, file, unix, awk

I have a file with 5 columns in the below format :

```
$cat test.txt
id;section;name;val1;val2
11;10;John;50;15
12;20;Sam;40;20
13;30;Jeny;30;30
14;10;Ted;60;10
15;10;Mary;30;5
16;20;Tim;15;15
17;30;Pen;20;100
```

I want to process the data in the file based on the section_number(column 2) passed . And I want to display the id,Name,Total(column4+column5) for the section_id passed . At the end i want to print the row information  that has the highest total .

I have already made a awk command like below :

```
 section=10 ; awk -F";" -v var="$section" 'BEGIN { print "id Name Total" } { if ($2 == var) { sum = $4 + $5 ;print $1 " "$3 " " sum ;if (sum>newsum) {newsum=sum;name=$3;id=$1}}} END { print "Max sum for section "var" is "newsum " for Name: " name " and ID: " id }' test.txt;
```

And it is  displaying the data as below :

```
id Name Total
11 John 65
14 Ted 70
15 Mary 35
Max sum for section 10 is 70 for Name: Ted and ID: 14
```

But how to handle the scenario if there are multiple records with the same highest value as Total ?

Comment: It all depends on how you would like to handle it i guess? You could say the first gets precedens `>`, the last `>=` or both by using arrays.

Comment: There can be any number of rows for each section with same Total . So how to track all those to print at the end ? For tracking one Total value I have done as above . But for multiple  same values I am not so familiar with awk and arrays .

Comment: For the input `id;section;name;val1;val2
11;10;John;50;15
12;20;Sam;40;20
13;30;Jeny;30;30
14;10;Ted;60;10
15;10;Mary;30;5
16;20;Tim;15;15
17;30;Pen;20;100
18;10;Mat;25;45` I am getting wrong Output `id Name Total
11 John 65
14 Ted 70
15 Mary 35
18 Mat 70
Max sum for section 10 is 70 for Name: Ted and ID: 14` . For correct it has to print the ID:18 also in the summary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how you would like to handle it i guess? You could say the first gets precedens `>`, the last `>=` or both by using arrays.

Assuming you want to show all having the same shared highest sum:

```
% cat script.awk
BEGIN {
  FS=";";
  print "id Name Total";
}
$2 != var {next}           # If line doesn't match skip blocks
{
  sum = $4 + $5;
  print $1 " " $3 " " sum;
}
sum > max {                # If sum > max we need to reset the arrays (names and ids)
  max = sum;               # because we get a new winner
  delete names;
  delete ids;
  l = 0;
}
sum >= max {               # If sum is same or higher than max we will need to add this
  l++;                     # to the list of winners.
  names[l] = $3;
  ids[l] = $1;
}
END {
  printf "Max sum for section %s is %d for\n", var, max;

  # Iterate though all "winners" and print them
  for ( i = 1; i <= l; i++ ) {
    printf "Name: %s, ID: %s\n", names[i], ids[i];
  }
}
```

Hope this gives you an idea of how to use arrays.

And running:

```
section=10;
awk -F";" -v var="$section" -f script.awk test.txt
#                           ^ Instead of having awk on command line use script.awk
```

Comment: While trying above code I am getting below errror `awk: syntax error at source line 12 source file script.awk
 context is
  names = >>>  [ <<< ];
awk: illegal statement at source line 13 source file script.awk
awk: illegal statement at source line 13 source file script.awk
`

Comment: Perfect ..It is working for me for the sample tests I made  . Now I have a small idea about array use from above awk script .thanks

Comment: @MathewsJose I'm glad I could help, you should consider reading it twice and then rewrite it yourself! I'm sure that will make it stick :-)